# In Swift, how do I know if words are wrapped in an UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, text, uilabel, word-wrap

In Swift, I wonder if there is a way to get whether or not a word is wrapped. For example, I have an UILabel.

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = "Hey! Hello World!"
label.areWordsWrapped()
```

If text is displaying like this:

```
Hey! Hell
o World!

//label.areWordsWrapped() should return true
```

if this:

```
Hey! Hello
World!

//label.areWordsWrapped() should return false
```

Is there a function or property to achieve that?

Comment: In both examples your text is wrapped. You want to check whether the text is wrapped at an "unbreakable" break point I guess?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans Sorry for the confusion, I mean the text has wrapped words.

Comment: This is very easy to do if you use a UITextView configured to behave like a label, because now you can just ask Text Kit.

Comment: @matt How do I accomplish this with UITextView?

Comment: As I said, you ask Text Kit how the text is laid out. It will tell you where all the line fragments are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, it may not perfect

```
extension UILabel {
func areWordsWrapped()->Bool {
    let fontAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: self.font!]
    let splitText: [String] = self.text!.split {$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
    for text in splitText {
        let width = text.size(withAttributes: fontAttributes).width
        if width > self.frame.width {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
}
```

edit:

it will be fail if you change the line break to character wrap
[image]

if use default line break it will be fine
[image]

if you use character wrap I think it almost certain it will be wrapped, because it almost impossible to have same width in every line without enter/new line

Comment: which case do you think it will failed?

Comment: You are comparing the width of each word, but what if each word fits, but two words on the same line break it?

Comment: I test that case, in default UILabel the second word will be in next line, it will fail only if you change line break to character wrap

Comment: Thx, I'll test this out on my end :)